# How can I display absolute div's beneath each other?

Tags: css

I've created a webpage with multiple flag banners using the class `flag` and `flag-category`. Both classes are set to `position:absolute` to show them uppon the image.

Now I want to display them beneath each other, so that they are in the same horizontal line. I already tried using `margin-left` / `margin-right` and `float:left`, but without success.

Here is the code:

```css
.flag {
position: absolute;
font-size: .7em;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: 700;
padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #f39;
border-radius: .4em 0 0 .4em;
margin: -25px -50px;
  }
```

```html
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='child-theme-css' href='http://vocaloid.de/wp-content/themes/Vuturize/style.css?ver=2.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
<body class="category">
  <div class="site-container">
    <div class="site-inner">
      <div class="content-sidebar-wrap">
        <main class="content">
          <article class="entry">
            <header class="entry-header">
              <div class="flag">Weekly VOCALOID Ranking</div>
              <div class="flag flag-category2">Daily Ranking</div>
              <div class="flag flag-category2">Events</div>
              <div class="flag flag-category2">Interviews</div>
              <div class="flag flag-category2">Merchandise</div>
              <img src="https://www.dnb.no/portalfront/bilder-dnb/mennesker/680/680-220-bedriftsmoete-3.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" />
            </header>
          </article>
        </main>
      </div>
</div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving each item a unique class and apply z-index on them so that they stack on top of each other.

Or you could redo the flags as List Items, and apply margin-right to them so that they do not overlap like how they do right now.

Either ways, your divs don't have enough space between each other.

Comment: Sure I could, but as I do not know if all of them get printed out, this is no good solution.. margin-left and right, as stated on top does not work, and renaming the element will not take any effect

Comment: Ok.  Alternatively, give each div an unique class or ID, and use top and left positioning to place them exactly where you want.  The top and left positioning is based off its parent relative position.

Answer (score 0):

Try one with absolute and one relative. 
Har du testat med en absolute och en relative?

```
.flag {
position: absolute;
font-size: .7em;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: 700;
padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #f39;
border-radius: .4em 0 0 .4em;
margin: -25px -50px;
  }

.flag:before {
content: ' ';
position: relative;
top: 0;
border-width: 26px 26px 0 0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #F39 transparent transparent;
right: -26px;
}

.flag-category2:after {
border-width: 4px;
border-color: #005357 #005357 transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to set fixed height to the flag css because some browsers will don´t know how to display it

Comment: Did not work.. changing .flag:before refers to the triangle of the trapeze shaped flag. Only the .flag class must be changed I think...